# Evaluate: $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\cdots}}}\, dx. $

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, nested-radicals

Is there a way to evaluate the integral:$$\int_0^1\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x^4+\cdots}}}}\,dx,$$ without using **numerical methods**?

The integrand doesn't seem to converge to anything for any arbitrary positive real $x$. I could be wrong also. Please suggest something..

**Edit.** Thank you everyone for your kind responses. These help a lot.. New ideas, techniques etc etc.. Thanks..

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683762/nested-radical-sqrtx-sqrtx2-cdots-sqrtxn-cdots) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747684/evaluate-sqrtx-sqrtx2-sqrtx3-sqrtx4). Does this help?

Comment: I upvoted the OP and the ABCD comment.  My (unproven) intuition is that $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3 + \cdots}}}$ is strictly increasing as $x$ goes from 0 to 1.  Therefore, based on the first link given in ABCD's comment, the function being integrated is bounded on $[0,1].$  That's as far as my thinking takes me.

Comment: Yes intuitively or based on the links provided it seems that the integrand is monotone increasing on $[0, 1]$ and also bounded above. So by *monotone convergence theorem* it must converge to its supremum. But I'm not actually able to find the supremum in $[0, 1]$. If it's $1$ then the integrand converges to $\varphi.$ Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory "not an answer but too long for comments"

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3+\dots}}}$

Surprisingly, from what I've gathered about the function from [this qustion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747684/evaluate-sqrtx-sqrtx2-sqrtx3-sqrtx4#comment7729368_3747684), not much is known even for the convergence of $f$ besides a few cases.

*However* it can be *approximated* extremely well.

It can easily be shown that $f(x)>\sqrt{2x}$, In fact it seems that $\lambda=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)-\sqrt{2x})\approx0.1767766$.

$\lambda$ is so exceptionally close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}$, I have yet to find a digit that does not match. However, my intuition tells me that it's only a coincidence. **Update:** As @Uwe points out in the comments, it is true that $\lambda=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}$

Hence $\sqrt{2x}+\lambda$ is an extremely good approximation for $f$. However, $\int_0^{\infty}(f(x)-(\sqrt{2x}+\lambda))$ does not converge (see comments for refferences).

Also for small values of $x$, $f(x)\approx1+\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: As described in this [partial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747684/evaluate-sqrtx-sqrtx2-sqrtx3-sqrtx4/3760817#3760817) the beginning of the asymptotic expansion for $x\to\infty$ is $f(x) = \sqrt{2x}(1+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{x}}-\frac{5}{128x}+\frac{85}{1024\sqrt{x^3}}+\mathcal{O}(x^{-2}))$. Thus indeed, $\lambda$ is exactly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}$, but $\int_0^\infty(f(x)-(\sqrt{2x}+\lambda))\mathrm{d}x$ does not converge at infinity. The above link gives also higher order approximations of $f(x)$ for small $x$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683885) is another reference, giving the asymptotic expansion for $f(x)$ at $x\to\infty$ in terms of $y=\sqrt{2x}$.

Comment: @Uwe Cheers! Fantastic update on your behalf.